# Project Image onto Cubemap

Tags: uv

I am quite new to Blender and Textures, so this Question has probaly asked before... I have got a skybox and an Image and I would like to project that image onto that Skybox, so that it looks undestorted when looking through the camera onto that part on the Skybox.

On the Image below I have tried to line out what I would like to do

[image]

What I basically want is that the projection on the right looks as the Image on the left, from that very Point of view.

All in all I need the UV-Map, is there any "standard procedure" I could apply?

Thanks in Ahead!

Comment: Use *Project from View* option in the *Unwrap* menu (`U`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make texture appear on the mesh just like you see it in 3D View window unwrap the mesh using <kbd>U</kbd> > *Project From View*. From the [wiki page](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/texturing/unwrapping.html?highlight=project%20from%20view#project-from-view):

> Project from View option maps the face as seen through the view of the 3D window it was selected from. It is almost like you had x-ray vision or squashed the mesh flat as a pancake onto the UV map.

[image]

Note that because this option takes into account only parts of the mesh which are pointed to the viewer in 3D View, you

> will get some stretching in areas where the model recedes away from you.

So use it when you know that you won't see areas in scene where faces of this mesh aren't pointed to camera.